# CSS inline-block alignment issue

Tags: css, html, formatting, alignment

I'm trying to get the pictures to get ".other-wrap" to vertically align with the picture on the left. I've tried adding a margin or a border but for some reason this pushes ".other-wrap" down and further out of alignment. Can anyone explain what's causing this behavior and what css I can add to ".other-wrap" to get it to align without changing the html structure.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wgthh/40/)

Html:

```
<div id="588970897807405-list" class="main">
<div id="588970897807405" class="main-wrap">
   <div class="inner-wrap">
      <div class="inner-name-wrap" style="font-size: 10pt;">
         <div class="inner-name">header</div>
      </div>
      <div class="inner-img-wrap">
         <img id="588970897807405-event-img" class="inner-img" src="http://nodogaboutit.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/j04310181.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="formatted-footer-wrap" style="font-size: 10pt;">
         <div class="footer">footer</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="other-wrap">
      <div class="other-inner">
         <div class="other-img-wrap"><img class="other-img" width="120" height="120" src="http://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/99059361-choose-cat-litter-632x475.jpg"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main .inner-img{
vertical-align:middle;
margin:auto;
display:block;
width:120px;
height:120px;
top:0px;
}

.other-wrap{

    /*border:solid black 15px;*/
    margin:15px;
}

.main .inner-name-wrap{
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:150px;
    font-size:14px;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    font-weight:normal;
    display:block;
    color:white;
    background:black;
}

.main .formatted-footer-wrap{
    color:white;
    display:block;
    font-size:10px;
    width:150px;
    background:black;
}

.main .other-wrap{
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:12px;
}

.main .formatted-time-wrap{
    display:none;
    font-size:10px;
}

.inner-wrap{
    display:inline-block;
    border:solid hsl(0, 100%, 100%) 1px;    
}
```

Comment: Really feel like you need to spend some more time with this. I'm not much for voting down, but I was close on this one. Reason: you're trying to achieve default behavior, and the solution requires someone else to deconstruct your code for you and figure out what's causing default behavior not to work. I'd suggest stripping all of this down until it does what it should do, then start adding things back in until you find what's breaking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align).

Try `vertical-align: middle`:

```
.main-wrap{
    font-size: 0; /* To fix extra space due to whitespaces in HTML */
}
.other-wrap, .inner-wrap{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 15px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wgthh/44/)